# Interview Question: What is the probability they will be home in more than 30 minutes?

Tags: probability, expected-value, random-walk

The following is an interview question:

A student leaves Univeristy (U) to walk Home (H). It is a distance of 4 blocks in a straight line. At each crossing, they toss a coin deciding whether to move forward (Heads) or backward (Tails). From U, they cannot go backward so they stay there. If it takes 7 minutes to walk each block, what is the probability they will be home in more than 30 minutes?

My thought process:

This is a random walk, the only time it will take less than 30 minutes is in two scenarios. First, if they flip 4 heads in a row (28 minutes to reach home), the probability of this is 1/16. The second scenario is if they start with flipping tails and then 4 heads from there, but you can have an infinite number of tails to begin with as you cannot move back from U so I don't know if this approach makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

The student can only make it home in under 30 minutes by going straight there. The first coin flip effectively must come up heads, since the student will just stay at U re-flipping as many times as needed instantaneously until they do find a Heads - any results of Tails to start the problem can be ignored, since they don't change the scenario and don't take up any time. Once the student has gotten their first Heads at time T=0 (despite *any number* of preceding Tails), the student needs to get Heads on their next 3 coin flips, which occurs with probability 1/8, and gets them home in 28 minutes. There is a 7/8 chance the student does not get 3 consecutive Heads and arrives home in more than 30 minutes.

The trick is to recognize that although the student does need 4 consecutive Heads to get home, the first one is guaranteed to occur at T=0, so there are only 3 proper "coin flips".

Answer (score 1):

This particular problem is simple enough that you are able to calculate the solution by narrowing down to all the particular paths that will satisfy the required condition (or its negation).  Using this method we find only one path that gets home in no more than 30 minutes (going directly home with no backward steps, which occurs with probability $(\tfrac{1}{2})^3 = \tfrac{1}{8}$).  This means that the probability of getting home after 30 minutes is $1- \tfrac{1}{8} = \tfrac{7}{8}$.

Although this solution method works in this simple case, in more complicated problems of this kind it is usually not feasible to count through all paths that meet a condition.  For this reason, I will show you how to calculate the solution using standard Markov chain analysis, which can easily be applied when the problem is made more complicated, with large numbers of paths meeting/not meeting the condition of interest.  The present method is overkill in this particular case, but it may be useful to help you understand how you can solve problems of this general kind even if they are more complicated than your particular problem.

---

This is the type of problem that can be solved by framing it as a discrete-time discrete-space Markov chain.  Letting $\mathscr{S} = \{ U,S_1,S_2,S_3,H \}$ denote the five spatial states you have described, and treating home as an absorbing state, the transition probability matrix for the Markov chain is:

$$\mathbf{P} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\tfrac{1}{2} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \tfrac{1}{2} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{2} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Over four time steps we get:

$$\mathbf{P}^4 =
\begin{bmatrix}
\tfrac{3}{8} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{2} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{8} \\
0 & \tfrac{5}{8} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{4} & \tfrac{1}{8} \\
\tfrac{1}{4} & 0 & \tfrac{3}{8} & 0 & \tfrac{3}{8} \\
0 & \tfrac{1}{4} & 0 & \tfrac{1}{8} & \tfrac{5}{8} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Suppose we let $T$ denote the number of steps required to move from the university to home (i.e., the "hitting time" for the home state when we start at the university).  The probability of interest to you is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(7 T > 30)
&= \mathbb{P}(T > 30/7) \\[6pt]&= \mathbb{P}(T > \lfloor 30/7 \rfloor) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(T > 4) \\[6pt]
&= 1-[\mathbf{P}^4]_{U,H} \\[6pt]
&= 1- \tfrac{1}{8} \\[6pt]
&= \tfrac{7}{8}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mathematica to calculate it.

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
n1 = Length@list1;
pairs1 = Table[{{list1[[i]], list1[[Mod[i - 1, n1, 1]]]} -> 
      1/2, {list1[[i]], list1[[Mod[i + 1, n1, 1]]]} -> 1/2}, {i, 2, 
     n1 - 1}] // Flatten;
finalTransferRule = {{list1[[1]], list1[[2]]} -> 1}~Join~pairs1~
  Join~{{list1[[-1]], list1[[-1]]} -> 1}
(transferMatrix = Normal@SparseArray[finalTransferRule]) // MatrixForm
\[CurlyPhi] = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, transferMatrix];
MarkovProcessProperties[\[CurlyPhi]];
PDF[\[CurlyPhi][n], k] // PiecewiseExpand // N;
\[ScriptCapitalD] = FirstPassageTimeDistribution[\[CurlyPhi], 5];
mypdf = PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD], k]
Table[N@mypdf, {k, 0, 20}]
DiscretePlot[mypdf, {k, 0, 20}, ExtentSize -> 1/2]
```

In this question, we focus on FirstPassageTimeDistribution: distribution of times for the Markov process to pass from the initial state (University, U) to the final state (Home, H) for the first time:

$$
p(k)=
\begin{cases}
 -2^{-k-\frac{5}{2}} \left((-1)^k+1\right) \left(\left(\sqrt{2}+2\right) \left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)^{k/2}+\left(\sqrt{2}-2\right) \left(\sqrt{2}+2\right)^{k/2}\right), & k>0 ,\\
 0,  &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

The values for `k=0..=20` are:

$$
{0., 0., 0., 0., 0.125, 0., 0.125, 0., 0.109375, 0., 0.09375, 0., \
0.0800781, 0., 0.0683594, 0., 0.0583496, 0., 0.0498047, 0., 0.042511}
$$

$$
\sum\limits_{k \geq 5} = 1- \frac{1}{8} =  \frac{7}{8}.
$$